Load Data from Database to the HTML Table in ASP.Net Core MVC
I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC C# project and need assistance with loading data from a database into an HTML table dynamically. Suppose that I have a controller and razor cshtml file. The below shown code is in the cshtml file. And how I can implement the controller for loading data from database and load the data into this table ???
        <style>
          table {
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            overflow: auto;
            overflow-y: overlay;
         }

        th, thead {
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
          border: 1px solid #dddddd;
          background-color: #1f2d54;
          text-align: center;
          color: white;
          table-layout: fixed;
          word-break: break-word;
          height: 45px;
        }          
       </style>

       <table style='padding: 8px;'>
       <thead>
        <tr>
             <th index=0>Email<div class="filter"></div></th>
             <th index=1>Name<div class="filter"></div></th>
             <th index=2>Level<div class="filter"></div></th>
             <th index=3>Location<div class="filter"></div></th>
        </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
    
         </tbody>
       </table>


Please show us your Controller code through which you are rendering your View. There are different plugins that you can use to enhance your UI but we will start with the basic table rendering using your CSS.

you can do it follow  the official tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio
Here's an example：
1). create a model named Users.cs
public class Users
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

2). Use the scaffolding tool to produce Create, Read, Update, and Delete (CRUD) pages for the Users model
3). Use the EF Core Migrations feature to create the database. Migrations is a set of tools that create and update a database to match the data model.
The result   is  as follows:

